# How to verify if Sitecore JSS is installed correctly

Tags: jss

How do I verify if the JSS server package is installed correctly in sitecore?

I have installed "JSS Server package -
Sitecore JavaScript Services Server for Sitecore 9.0 11.0.0 rev. 181031" by following the documentation:
https://jss.sitecore.com/docs/getting-started/jss-server-install

As mentioned, when I browse the below url: `http://<sitecore_host_name>/sitecore/api/layout/render/jss?item=/&sc_apikey=TEST`, it responds with following resopnse

This page isn’t working. If the problem continues, contact the site owner.
HTTP ERROR 400

Current Sitecore version - 9.0.2

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although a little counter intuitive, this does seem like the expected response to verify the server components are installed correctly.  The server should return a 400 with an invalid API key such as "TEST".

The documentation you linked to does actually state this, but can see why it's a little confusing.

> Verify your server components install worked, by visiting http://your-sitecore-instance/sitecore/api/layout/render/jss?item=/&sc_apikey=TEST. You **should** receive HTTP Error 400.0 - API key is not valid ***if it is working correctly***.

In Step two of the next section of the guide (App Deployment), there are instructions on how to set up an API key.
https://jss.sitecore.com/docs/getting-started/app-deployment

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I was expecting "API key is not valid" in the response. However after following the step two as you have mentioned above, I got the desired response.